# How to determine rook's available moves?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, chess

I am making a chess implementation on HTML5. The game has a feature to determine available moves of a piece on tapping.

[image: example image]

For example, tapping the the rook at a1 should highlight a2,a3 and a4 as its available moves.

I am able to achieve that but the problem is that it highlights even c1, a5, a6, a7 and a8.

How can I prevent this.
i.e. how can I determine such unwanted blocks from my array of available moves.

Some cues:

**->** Blocks are divs of id like `"a1"`,`"a2"`

**->** I already have array (as I said) of legal moves(eg: `legal = ["a2","a3","a4","a5","a6"...]`). I just want to remove the unwanted ones.

**->** language: JavaScript or jQuery

> Thank you so much

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) - This is not a question fit for stackoverflow but possibly at [CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Balgorithms%5D+chess)

Comment: Don't show us meaningless image, you should also include the relevant code (html/css/js) and provide clear explanation about the issue you're having with it

Comment: The image is for refference to demonstrate my problem. As is said, the problem is how to eliminate the unwanted elements from the list. I don't know how to do it and so can't post some code. I have no idea and hence am asking here for help

Comment: So it's just a simple matter of using the [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) then? This is how you remove elements from an array - https://jsfiddle.net/m25c30vp/

Comment: Thanks...But how do I determine programmatically which elements to remove?

Answer (score 0):

When calculating legal moves you want the array to include at least from_square and to_square. Then you know that all rook moves are the ones with from_square == a1.

Comment: I have those stored in a javascript object and it works well...but the issue is that it also shows moves that are achieved after jumpimg(like knight)...i want to eliminate those from the array

Comment: You go through each direction in a loop. If the next square is empty, add and continue to next square. If next square is own piece, dont add and continue with next direction. If finding enemy piece, add to list and continue to next direction.

Comment: Great...i was also thinking something similar.... thanks:-)

Comment: Finally achieved....thank you everyone for your help...